# Hive load data OpenCSVSerde comment control

Tags: csv, hive

**How to produce the problem:**

1. Create a table use the hive create SQL, such as:

```
create table `db`.`table`(
    `field1` string,
    `field2` string,
    `field3` string
) row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde';
```

2. Load csv file use the hive load data SQL, such as:

```
load data local inpath 'my/file/path' overwrite into table `db`.`table`;
```

The table schema will be:

```
field1                  string                  from deserializer
field2                  string                  from deserializer
field3                  string                  from deserializer
```

Noticed that the comment of every field will be 'from deserializer'.

**My question:**
How can I get rid of this comment OR customize the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Set this `set hive.serdes.using.metastore.for.schema=org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde;`param in your **hive shell** then you can have **`empty comment`** (or) **`custom comment`**.

```
hive> set hive.serdes.using.metastore.for.schema=org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde;

hive> create table `db`.`table`(
    `field1` string COMMENT '',
    `field2` string COMMENT 'fiel2 comment',
    `field3` string COMMENT 'field3 comment'
) row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde';

hive> desc formatted table;

OK
# col_name              data_type               comment

field1                  string
field2                  string                  field2 comment
field3                  string                  field3 comment
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried your method, but it doesn't work. Comments are still 'from deserializer'. What's the version of your hive?

Comment: @callofdutyops, i'm using **`Hive 2.1.1`** and tried in Hive cli, not in beeline..!

Comment: I'm sorry that it doesn't help me. I change to the default CSV Serde.