pyhive use OpenCSVSerde
I want to create a table via pyhive and then do load csv data. OpenCSVSerde causes the type to be converted to string, and the comment will be from deserializer. So I set the hive.serdes.using.metastore.for.schema property. Hive CLI can be executed successfully, but it cannot be executed in pyhive, why is this?
conn = hive.connect(
    host=hive_host,
    port=hive_port,
    auth='LDAP',
    username=hive_username,
    password=hive_password,
    configuration={
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57984635/hive-load-data-opencsvserde-comment-control
        'hive.serdes.using.metastore.for.schema': 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
    }
)

cursor = conn.cursor()
create_table = """
create table dwtmp.test_importer_data (
    `name` string COMMENT 'test',
    `age` int
) row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    "separatorChar" = ',',
    "quoteChar"     = '\"'
)
tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1")
"""
cursor.execute(create_table)

cursor.execute('set hive.serdes.using.metastore.for.schema')
result = cursor.fetchall()
for row in result:
    print(row)

out: ('hive.serdes.using.metastore.for.schema=org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde',)
hive> desc dwtmp.test_importer_data;
OK
name                    string                  from deserializer
age                     string                  from deserializer
Time taken: 0.134 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)

hive> drop table dwtmp.test_importer_data;
OK
Time taken: 0.302 seconds
hive> set hive.serdes.using.metastore.for.schema=org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde;
hive> create table dwtmp.test_importer_data (
    >     `name` string COMMENT 'test',
    >     `age` int
    > ) row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
    > WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    >     "separatorChar" = ',',
    >     "quoteChar"     = '\"'
    > )
    > tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1");
OK
Time taken: 0.371 seconds
hive> desc dwtmp.test_importer_data;
OK
name                    string                  test
age                     int
Time taken: 0.132 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)

